# Merge gradle of Custom Templates in Android studio

Tags: templates, android-studio

I try to custom template,but I can't correctly merge gradle.
the following codes is missed,how to solve the problem?  thanks in advance

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
provided 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
```

**build.gradle.ftl**

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
    provided 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
}
```

**recipe.xml.ftl**

```
<merge from="root/build.gradle.ftl"
            to="${escapeXmlAttribute(projectOut)}/build.gradle" />
```

**build.gradle** after merge

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add dependencies directly in recipe.xml.ftl:

```
<dependency mavenUrl="com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2" gradleConfiguration="apt"/>
<dependency mavenUrl="javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2" gradleConfiguration="provided" />
```